# Não estou conseguindo ler as strings com espaço e armazena-las

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dado_cidade {
    char cidade[20];
    float taxa_2009;
    float taxa_2015;
    float indice_percent;
} cidades[27];

int main () {

    FILE *dados;
    dados = fopen("dados_tabela.txt", "r");

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        fscanf(dados, "%s %f %f %f", &cidades[i].cidade, &cidades[i].taxa_2009, &cidades[i].taxa_2015); 
        cidades[i].indice_percent = cidades[i].taxa_2015 - cidades[i].taxa_2009;
    }

    fclose(dados);

    // for (i=0; i<27; i++) {
    //     printf("%s %f %f %f\n", cidades[i].cidade, cidades[i].taxa_2009, cidades[i].taxa_2015, cidades[i].indice_percent);
    // }

    printf("%s", cidades[2].cidade);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

"Rondonia"      97.8    57.7
"Acre"          41.4    58.9
"Amazonas"      109.9   78.8
"Roraima"       125 96.4
"Para"          73.2    72.9
"Amapa"         37.6    110.8
"Tocantins"     97  85.6
"Maranhao"      109.7   116.5
"Piaui"         100.1   103.6
"Ceara"         66.2    49.1
"Rio Grande do Norte"   63.1    68.4
"Paraiba"           64.9    81.8
"Pernambuco"        62.1    67.6
"Alagoas"           34.3    59.1
"Sergipe"           118.6   51.6
"Bahia"         101.8   75.4
"Minas Gerais"      52.1    47
"Espirito Santo"        91.3    73.1
"Rio de Janeiro"        93.7    67.1
"Sao Paulo"     56.6    50.8
"Parana"            71.7    51.7
"Santa Catarina"        32.2    30.9
"Rio Grande do Sul" 67.3    43.4
"Mato Grosso do Sul"    126.7   88.2
"Mato Grosso"       85.9    82.9
"Goias"         50.7    56.6
"Distrito Federal"  67.3    43.7

Ao mandar ler esses dados que se encontra no arquivo os espaços nas strings são interpretadas como um único input por espaço.

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão a função `fscanf` vai ler até encontrar um espaço `" "`.

Você precisa especificar que sua sequência de caracteres está entre aspas no pattern:

```
fscanf(dados, "\"%[^\"]\" %f %f %f", &cidades[i].cidade, &cidades[i].taxa_2009, &cidades[i].taxa_2015);
```